# Sqlite - SELECT or INSERT and SELECT in one statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to avoid writing separate SQL queries to achieve the following scenario:

I have a Table called Values:

Values:

```
id INT (PK)
data TEXT
```

I would like to check if certain data exists in the table, and if it does, return its id, otherwise insert it and return its id.

The (very) naive way would be:

```
select id from Values where data = "SOME_DATA";
```

if id is not null, take it.
if id is null then:

```
insert into Values(data) values("SOME_DATA");
```

and then select it again to see its id or use the returned id.

I am trying to make the above functionality in one line.
I think I'm getting close, but I couldn't make it yet:
So far I got this:

```
select id from Values where data=(COALESCE((select data from Values where data="SOME_DATA"), (insert into Values(data) values("SOME_DATA"));
```

I'm trying to take advantage of the fact that the second select will return null and then the second argument to COALESCE will be returned. No success so far. What am I missing?

Comment: There are a lot of similarities, maybe the answer will come from the MySQL thread :P

Comment: The behavior you want is vendor-specific. Some vendors provide a way to return the inserted/delete values from insert/update commands. For example, in SQL Server you can output a new ID using the OUTPUT clause without locking, while MySQL has the LAST_INSERT_ID to return the last auto-generated ID

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your command does not work because in SQL, `INSERT` does not return a value.

If you have a unique constraint/index on the `data` column, you can use that to prevent duplicates if you blindly insert the value; this uses [SQLite's `INSERT OR IGNORE` extension](http://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html):

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO "Values"(data) VALUES('SOME_DATE');
SELECT id FROM "Values" WHERE data = 'SOME_DATA';
```

Comment: I see, so you suggest insert anyway (worst case it will be ignored) and then select. I was trying to do it in a one liner, but didn't seem to work. Thanks!

Comment: How can the ignore work if the data are not unique? example: autoID, A, B, C. `INSERT ... VALUES(A, B, C)` inserts a new row.

Comment: @Sandburg The [IGNORE clause](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) depends on some constraint (UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY). If there is no such constraint, it would not make sense to ask whether the data already exists in the table.

Comment: This does the lookup twice though surely?

Comment: @Timmmm There is no way to do it with one lookup. In any case, a UNIQUE or PK constraint implies an index, and that value will be cached.

Comment: As of sqlite 3.35.0 you can use a [`RETURNING` clause](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_returning.html) to do this in a single statement. As mentioned in a comment to the original post, the approach depends on the backend.