# Efficient insertion of row and foreign table row if it does not exist

Tags: sqlite

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250386/sqlite-select-or-insert-and-select-in-one-statement) and [this solution for PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/46477) (in particular "INSERT missing FK rows at the same time"):

Suppose I am making an address book with a "Groups" table and a "Contact" table. When I create a new Contact, I may want to place them into a Group at the same time. So I could do:

```
INSERT INTO Contact VALUES (
  "Bob",
  (SELECT group_id FROM Groups WHERE name = "Friends")
)
```

But what if the "Friends" Group doesn't exist yet? Can we insert this new Group efficiently?

The obvious thing is to do a SELECT to test if the Group exists already; if not do an INSERT. Then do an INSERT into Contacts with the sub-SELECT above.

Or I can constrain `Group.name` to be UNIQUE, do an INSERT OR IGNORE, then INSERT into Contacts with the sub-SELECT.

I can also keep my own cache of which Groups exist, but that seems like I'm duplicating functionality of the database in the first place.

My guess is that there is no way to do this in one query, since INSERT does not return anything and cannot be used in a subquery. Is that intuition correct? What is the best practice here?

Comment: I just take the insert or ignore approach when I need to do this.

Answer (score 2):

> My guess is that there is no way to do this in one query, since INSERT
>   does not return anything and cannot be used in a subquery. Is that
>   intuition correct?

You could use a **Trigger** and a little modification of the tables and then you could do it with a single query.

## For example consider the folowing

#### Purely for convenience of producing the demo:-

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS add_group_if_not_exists;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contact;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS groups;
```

### One-time setup SQL :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS groups (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, group_name TEXT UNIQUE);
INSERT INTO groups VALUES(-1,'NOTASSIGNED');
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contact (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, contact TEXT, group_to_use TEXT, group_reference TEXT DEFAULT -1 REFERENCES groups(id));
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS add_group_if_not_exists 
AFTER INSERT ON contact
BEGIN
 INSERT OR IGNORE INTO groups (group_name) VALUES(new.group_to_use);
 UPDATE contact SET group_reference = (SELECT id FROM groups WHERE group_name = new.group_to_use), group_to_use = NULL WHERE id = new.id;  
END;
```

## SQL that would be used on an ongoing basis :-

```
INSERT INTO contact (contact,group_to_use) VALUES
        ('Fred','Friends'),
        ('Mary','Family'),
        ('Ivan','Enemies'),
        ('Sue','Work colleagues'),
        ('Arthur','Fellow Rulers'),
        ('Amy','Work colleagues'),
        ('Henry','Fellow Rulers'),
        ('Canute','Fellow Ruler')
;
```

- The number of values and the actual values would vary.

#### SQL Just for demonstration of the result

```
SELECT * FROM groups;
SELECT contact,group_name FROM contact JOIN groups ON group_reference = groups.id;
```

## Results

This results in :-

1) The groups (noting that the group "NOTASSIGNED", is intrinsic to the working of the above and hence added initially) :-

[image]

- have to be careful regard mistakes like (Fellow Ruler instead of Fellow Rulers)
- **-1** used because it would not be a normal value automatically generated.

2) The contacts with the respective group :-

[image]

> Efficient insertion

That could likely be debated from here to eternity so I leave it for the fence sitters/destroyers to decide :). However, some considerations:-

- It works and appears to do what is wanted.
- It's a little wasteful due to the additional wasted column.
- It tries to minimise the waste by changing the column to an empty string (NULL may be even more efficient, but for some can be confusing)
- There will obviously be an overhead BUT in comparison to the alternatives probably negligible (perhaps important if you were extracting every Facebook user) but if it's user input driven likely irrelevant.

> What is the best practice here?

Fences again. :)

> **Note** Hopefully obvious, but the DROP statements are purely for convenience and that all other SQL **up until the INSERT** is run once
>   to setup the tables and triggers in preparation for the single INSERT
>   that adds a group if necessary.